# Why is $x=2 \implies (x-2)(x-3)=0$ false?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic, roots, quadratics

Let $P(x)$ be the equation $x=2$
and $Q(x)$ be the equation  $(x-2)(x-3)=0$

By definition of implication I see that $P(x)$ implies $Q(x)$...

As I see it, any premise that is false can give any consequence.
With $x=2$ both sides of the arrow are true.. so implication is true.

It is clear that $Q(x)$ implies $P(x)$ and it is also clear that $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are not equivalent. Since $Q(x)$ implies $P(x)$ and $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are not equivalent it follows that $P(x)$ cannot imply $P(x)$.

Where am I wrong?

EDIT: I knew that $P(x)\Leftrightarrow Q(x)$ was not valid. And I thought wrongly that $P(x)\Leftarrow Q(x)$ is valid which should, if it was valid, imply that $P(x)\nRightarrow Q(x)$. But testing $P(x)\Rightarrow Q(x)$ by the truth table showed $P(x)\Rightarrow Q(x)$ is valid which confused me. I was simply wrongly thinking $P(x)\Leftarrow Q(x)$ which is the correct answer. I have also posted a soultion below, which typo is corrected.

Comment: It's not false.

Comment: What is so great about this question that it has 2 upvotes?

Comment: It seems true to me. Are you sure you didn't copy the question wrong?

Comment: And I was not implying that it should get compensational downvotes.

Comment: I just understood OP's question: He says the biconditional must be false, but he does not understand how reach that conclusion.

Comment: It is incorrect because the equation x-2=0 is not equivalent to the equation (x-2)(x-3)=0 where in the latter one x=3 is a solution.

Comment: You write at the end "It is clear that $Q$ implies $P$", but this is wrong: $Q$ does not, in fact, imply $P$. If $x=3$, then $Q$ is true but $P$ is false.

Comment: $x=2 \implies (x-2)(x-3)=0$ is true, but $(x-2)(x-3)=0 \implies x=2$ is false, hence $x=2 \iff (x-2)(x-3)=0$ is false.

Comment: @ Akiva, I made up the question.

Comment: @ barak, How about this? $x=3\Leftarrow x^2=9$, I've seen the notation a lot.

Comment: @GyroGearloose I find pretty funny how your comment earned the question 5 downvotes (unintentionally, of course), haha.

Comment: @user300627 That statement in your most recent comment is **false**: $(x=3$ or $x=-3) \leftarrow x^2=9$ would be true.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD : the one thing I will never be able to understand are social mechanics. As of now, the question is has one up, so I think I didn't too much harm. I have not enough reputation to look into the votes on how it decomposes into up/downs.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD and while I was writing the above comment, the votes decresed to 0 and got up to 1 again. The world is crazy. The only fact that I can take comfort is that the original question has enough and good answers.

Comment: The question is +7/-6 at the moment. I have not cast a vote yet: I think that the question **can't** be answered in the current state, making a leap of faith, as I've said before, I think OP's confusing an implication with a biconditional. So the question is ill-posed. I would think people would consider this before answering the same things many times, but oh well.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD the OP has been absent now for quite awhile, so any additional effort is in vain until some feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your comment to Jack Bauer's answer you write

> "it is supposed to be false since x=3 is a solution... but by the definition of implication I see it true... what is wrong?"

The problem is when you say "It is supposed to be false since $x=3$ is a solution." The fact that $x=3$ is a solution does not make "$P\implies Q$" false; it makes "$Q\implies P$" false. There is absolutely no problem with saying "$P$ implies $Q$, but is not equivalent to $Q$."

Comment: I think that Q implies P. And if Q implies P then Q and P are equivalent... but they are not.

Comment: @user300627 **Why do you think that $Q$ implies $P$?** It clearly doesn't - if $x=3$, then $Q$ is true, but $P$ is false.

Comment: Right..for x=3 Q is true and P is false.. and then the implication is also false... meaning Q implies P is correct. It still follows the definition which is Q=T, P=F, Q->P = F

Comment: @user300627 If Q is true and P is false, then Q implies P is false. P implies Q is true. **These are different statements**. In fact, at the end of your comment you (correctly) write "Q$\implies$ P = F"! I truly do not understand why you think "Q implies P" is true.

Answer (score 4):

$$(x-2)(x-3)=0 \iff x = 2 \ \, \text{or} \, \ x = 3$$

If $x=2$, then the hypothesis of the RHS is satisfied and hence we have the LHS.

I don't see why that is supposed to be false.

Comment: it is supposed to be false since x=3 is a solution... but by the definition of implication I see it true... what is wrong?

Comment: @user300627 the converse $Q(x) \to P(x)$ is false.

Comment: @user300627 Certainly $x=2$ implies that $x=2$ or $x=3$. Should it by any chance have been a biimplication?

Comment: How is Q(x)→P(x) false?

Maybe I use wrong definition?

Comment: @user300627 The proposition 'user300627 is male implies user300627 is male or female' is true. The converse is false.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you mean the converse $Q(x) \Rightarrow P(x)$...that is false. If $(x-2)(x-3) =0$, then $x=2$ or $x=3$, so it is not necessarily the case that $x=2$.

Comment: this is OK
(x−2)(x−3)=0 -> x=2

this is not OK
(x−2)(x−3)=0(x−2)(x−3)=0 <- x=2

and I cannot see why not OK.

Comment: How you got the arrow sign, are you using latex?

Comment: @user300627 No, $P \Rightarrow Q$ and $Q \Leftarrow P$ are saying the exact same thing. It's like how $a<b$ and $b>a$ are the same. The arrow sign is using LaTeX (command \Rightarrow or \Leftarrow )

Comment: Right.. but I only switched the arrow.. I did not switch P and Q... In other words equation x-2=0 is not equivalent to (x-2)(x-3)=0 since in the latter one x=3 is a solution.

Comment: @user300627 Yes exactly the equations are not equivalent. $x=2$ is stronger since it says $x=2$ but $(x-2)(x-3)=0$ just means $x=2$ or $x=3$, which follows automatically from $x=2$ but is not the same

Comment: And since they are not equivalent, the arrow to one of the directions is false.

Comment: @ Yep. The statements are equivalent if and only if both directions are true

Comment: nice............+1 @aras

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is in how to understand logical expressions and how to use them. If you look at the truth table of $P\Rightarrow Q$, you have:
\begin{array}{ccc}
P&Q&(P\Rightarrow Q)\\\hline
T&T&T\\
T&F&F\\
F&T&T\\
F&F&T
\end{array}
Therefore you are correct in saying that if $P$ is false, then $P\Rightarrow Q$ is true, no matter what $Q$ is. This doesn't mean, however that $Q$ must be true.

The way to use the logical statements is:
\begin{align}
P \text{ is true}&&\color{blue}{\text{and}}&&(P\Rightarrow Q)\text{ is true}
\end{align}
imply that
\begin{equation}
Q\text{ is true}.
\end{equation}

Let's apply this to $Q\Rightarrow P$. In order to infer that $P$ is true, you need
\begin{align}
Q \text{ is true}&&\color{blue}{\text{and}}&&(Q\Rightarrow P)\text{ is true}.
\end{align}
Here we run into a problem. As was mentioned in other answers and comments, if $Q$ is true, this means that $x=2$ or $x=3$. So $Q\Rightarrow P$ is false. We can't infer that $P$ is true.

Answer (score 2):

There is a tacit "$\forall x$" here that should be discussed.  That is, if $P(x)$ is the proposition "$x=2$" and $Q(x)$ is the proposition $(x-2)(x-3)=0$, the full-fledged logical statements whose true/false status is in question are

$$\forall x(P(x)\implies Q(x))\quad\text{and}\quad \forall x(Q(x)\implies P(x))$$

The first of these is true, the second is false.  The reason the second is false is simple:  $Q(3)$ is true, but $P(3)$ is false, so the implication $Q(x)\implies P(x)$ is *not* true for *all* $x$.  (Note, the implication *is* true for all $x$ other than $3$, mostly because the proposition $Q(x)$ is false for most values of $x$.)

It's perhaps worth adding why the statement $\forall x(P(x)\implies Q(x))$ is true.  The propositions $P(2)$ and $Q(2)$ are both true, so the implication $P(2)\implies Q(2)$ is true.  For all $x$ other than $2$, the proposition $P(x)$ is false, which makes any implication beginning "$P(x)\implies\ldots$" automatically true.  Hence the implication $P(x)\implies Q(x)$ is true for all $x$.

Answer (score 1):

$$(2-2)(2-3)=0(-1)=0$$

In what universe is that false?

Comment: Are you talking about modal logic? I am using following implication where P - > Q is equivalent to not(P and not Q)

Answer (score 0):

In the logic of statement, $P \Rightarrow Q$ is only wrong when $P$ is wrong, $Q$ is true. You can read here for more details https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional. (mainly on the **Truth table** section)

In your question, it is a statement depend on variable $x$, that means the characteristic of true or wrong of $P(x) \Rightarrow Q(x)$ depend on the value of $x$.

Go on more specific, $x=2 \Rightarrow (x-2)(x-3)=0$, we consider $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (of course you can deal with the case $x \in \mathbb{C}$)

$\bullet  x=2$, we get $2=2 \Rightarrow (2-2)(2-3)=0$, or $P(x), Q(x)$ are true, so the statement is true

$\bullet x \neq 2$, we conclude that  $P(x)$ is always wrong, so by the Truth table, the statement is true
Conlusion: $P(x) \Rightarrow Q(x)$ is always true

So, apply the same method, you can answer why we can't use the argument $Q(x) \Rightarrow P(x)$, because when $x=3$, $Q(x)$ is wrong, $P(x)$ is true, so the statement $Q(x) \Rightarrow P(x)$ is wrong, of course it is true for $x \neq 3$ but if you want to use this, you must restrict to condition $x\neq 3$.

*A little further*: this question remind me of the reasonable transformations in solving an equation. That is  $P(x) =0 \Rightarrow Q(x)=0$ if and only if the solution set of $P(x)$ is a subset of the solution set of $Q(x)$, that means $P(x) \Rightarrow Q(x)$ is alwayse true if and only if the solution set of $P(x)$ is a subset of the solution set of $Q(x)$ (you can use the method above to prove that). When the solution set of $P(x)$ is exactly the same as the solution set of $Q(x)$, we can write $P(x)\Leftrightarrow Q(x)$. That make sense because when you solve $Q(x)$, there are some solution of $Q(x)$ that not the solution of $P(x)$ and you have to check again (this section is one of the most section that high school student often forget)

Answer (score 0):

Usually in logic, we talk about truth value for *sentences*, which are formulas without free variables. Here you have a free variable $x$. However, for any particular choice of $x$ the statement is true.

Answer (score -1):

For the case $P(x)\Rightarrow Q(x)$:

If we choose $x=2$ then we got true on both sides of the arrow. If we choose $x\neq 2$ then P(x) is false and Q(x) can be false (if $x\neq 3$) or true (if $x=3$).
The implication $P(x)\Rightarrow Q(x)$ is therefore valid.

Following explanation will explain why I was wrong. This is for the case $P(x)\Leftarrow Q(x)$:

If we choose $x=2$ then we got true on both sides of the arrow.
If we choose $x=3$ then we got Q(x) is true and P(x) is false. Since this scenario is possible, it means the implication $P(x)\Leftarrow Q(x)$ is not valid, i.e. we have $P(x)\nLeftarrow Q(x)$.

A bit more intuitive and more self explaining similar example is when we consider $x=3 \Rightarrow x^2=9$ which is fully valid. What if we change the direction of the arrow in the implication? Changing direction of the arrow, gives us $x=3 \nLeftarrow x^2=9$ since $x=-3$ is true for $x^2=9$ but not for $x=3$.

Comment: **This is still wrong!** At the end of your fourth paragraph you have "$Q$ true, P false" is possible - you now conclude that $Q\implies P$ is false, not that $P\implies Q$ is false!

Comment: if $(x-2)(x-3)=0 \Rightarrow x=2$ is false, then why is $(x+3)(x-3)=0 \Rightarrow x=3$ correct?

Comment: **It's not correct.** They're both false. The **other** direction, $x=3\implies (x+3)(x-3)=0$ [or, equivalently, $(x+3)(x-3)=0\leftarrow (x=3)$], is correct. Think about it in natural language: is it the case that, if $(x-2)(x-3)=0$, then $x=2$? No, it's not. So "$Q\implies P$" is false. Meanwhile, is it the case that, if $x=2$, then $(x-2)(x-3)=0$? Yes, it is. So "$P\implies Q$" is true.

Comment: isn't that what I was saying?

Comment: maybe you missed $\nLeftarrow$... there is a line over the arrow.

Comment: It's your fourth paragraph that's wrong - your fifth paragraph is correct. In your fourth paragraph, you should have $Q\not\rightarrow P$, but you have $P\not\rightarrow Q$. (Also, in your previous comment, you seem to believe that "$(x+3)(x-3)=0\implies x=3$" is correct - it's not.)

Comment: Thank you.. now I see my typo :D:D:D